# text replacement technique in find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails has a nice technique of replacing `?` in an SQL statement by one or several objects, such as:

`User.find_by_sql("select * from users where uid in (?)", [1,2,3])`

How do I implement this technique to my own custom query? I checked the source code for this and similar methods but couldn't find it.

In my case I have fql_query from Koala gem, which does not accommodate passing in objects to sql query. I would like to extend this method so that it allows inserting dynamic arguments to query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` from [ActiveRecord::Sanitization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html) to do SQL escaping for conditions clauses.

If you need more general sanitization, you can use `quote` from [ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Quoting](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html).